# How to hidden locale code in Nextjs + next-i18next?

Tags: next.js, locale, next-i18next

my project using next-i18next in Nextjs.

In my project now, url shows the locale code.

`next-i18next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    locales: [
      'en-US',
      'zh-CN',
      'zh-TW',
      'ja-JP',
    ],
    localeDetection: false,
    pages: {
      '*': ['common'],
    },
  },
};
```

I want feature to hidden locale code in url.
Any idea how to hide locale code in url?

Thanks :)